# iOS - Difference between two times (ignore dates)

Tags: ios, nsdate

How can I find the difference between two NSDates but ignore the date and only care about the time?

So far, I've found lots of solutions to calculate the difference between NSDates but none that ignore the date and only care about the time.

e.g., The difference betweeen 01/01/01 04:35 PM and 01/09/09 04:36 PM is 1 minute

Answer (score 1):

As with everything date calculation related on iOS, `NSCalendar` has got you covered! Specifically, you want to use `components:fromDate:toDate:options:` and pass `NSWrapCalendarComponents` as the option, which will prevent overflowing of components into the higher date components.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int (^timeFromDate)(NSDate *) = ^(NSDate *date) {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:date];

    return (components.hour * 60 + components.minute) * 60 + components.second;
};
int diff = timeFromDate(date1) - timeFromDate(date2);
```

Comment: The sum `components.hour + components.minute + components.second` makes no sense.

Comment: @JesseRusak why? please explain?

Comment: So, the time 3:41:22 would return 3 + 41 + 22 = 66. How does that help?

Comment: If anything, it should be: `return components.hour * 3600 + components.minute * 60 + components.second;`

Comment: @JesseRusak you are right, my fault, I've updated answer.